# Assertions which does not throw an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert, assertion

We need some kind of functionality similar to Assertions, but which should not throw exceptions. Instead, this functionality can keep track of failed verifications and give the list when needed.

We need this in GUI automation. There are many pages where we make lots of verifications, and if a verification fails, we want to continue making the rest. This is because constructing GUI is an expensive process and we don't want to fail the test as a whole, because one amount in one confirmation page is calculated wrong.

IBM Rational Functional Tester has a similar built in functionality called Verification Points. We need a similar in C#.

We coded a couple of simple methods which does this, but it is a burden to code the Assertion library with so much overloads as a whole again.

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2106467-coded-ui-have-a-continue-on-error-for-asserts

Comment: Just use a logging system, so print to a log if a value is incorrect

Comment: In two of my projects, we wrote our own ErrorAggregator or AssertionAggregator.

Comment: Which framework you are using for testing?

Comment: @Matias yes this is what I'm looking for, and it is an obvious need. Thanks for the link, but it is declined.

Comment: @Sergey we're using Visual Studio 2013. MSTest to be precise.